# Can't select/deselect an item on a Slicer - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

the problem is that whenever I run the macro nothing really happens on the slicer - I mean no item is selected. I need to filter by month - automatically, depending on the current date. What's wrong with the code?
I need to underscore that my pivot tables are created on data model:

```
Sub Archive()

    Dim i As SlicerItem
    Dim ostWierszWS As Long
    Dim zakres As Range
    Dim zakres_ws As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each i In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Month").SlicerItems
        If i.Value = Month(Now) Then
            i.Selected = True
        Else
            i.Selected = False
        End If
    Next i
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set WS = Worksheets("Archive")
    Set zakres = Worksheets("aaa").Range("D7:D10")
    ostWierszWS = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set zakres_ws = WS.Cells(ostWierszWS, 3)
    
    zakres.Copy
    zakres_ws.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    
    Set WS = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Sheets("aaa").Activate
End Sub
```

---

Ok, I digged into the topic and now know that .SlicerCacheLevel.SlicerItems let me get into item on slicer list. Now the problem is that I can't select specific month on the slicer list. Let's say we have 5 elements on a list (March, April, May, June, July) which means that array consists of 5 elements (1 to 5). So, if we have July now (7) I can't in any way select 7 on a slicer. Looping through doesn't work out as well. How can it be solved? Look at my code:

```
Sub Archive()

Dim i As SlicerItem
Dim varrSlicerItems As Variant
Dim k As Long

    
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Month")

        ReDim varrSlicerItems(1 To .Slicers("Month").SlicerCacheLevel.SlicerItems.Count)

        For Each i In .Slicers(1).SlicerCacheLevel.SlicerItems
            k = k + 1
            varrSlicerItems(k) = i.Name
        Next i

        'and ERROR occurs here...
         .VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array(varrSlicerItems(Month(Date)))



    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked what i.value actually looks like?

Comment: I think it's String but not sure. When replace Month(Now) with "7" (July) then macro works. When I put 7 it doesn't work. Anyways macro works for now i.Value=Month(now). The funny thing is that I created 2 seperate spreadsheets - one based on data (placed in one of the sheets) and second on data model and used the SAME macro for both. For simple data it works - for data model - no. Maybe here is the point?

Comment: You can get the type by stepping your macro to that line and then typing  ?TYPENAME(i.value) in your immediate pane and hitting enter. Or you can change the test to: Cstr(i.Value) = CStr(Month(Now))